# Possible migrating openssh-server fingerprint?

Tags: ssh, man-in-the-middle

I have upgrade my server to a new OS and newer hardware.

But newly installed OS generated a new set of fingerprint / server keys. Is there anyway I could copy it from my old server to new server. In order to remove the security warning from clients?

EDIT: OS change is from ubuntu 11.10 -> 12.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ssh key for the server itself**

the files you'd like to migrate are defined in your sshd's config by HostKey directive.

in debian you'd find them in /etc/ssh , under that distro keys are called ssh_host_* ; just search your etc directory for ssh:

```
find /etc |grep ssh
```

you'll find them somewhere. after copying restart your sshd server.

**list of 'known hosts'**

it's something used to check identity of remote machines when you log in from your server to another computers. you'll find it in your home directory - ~/.ssh/known_hosts. just copy this file from the old server to the new one.

Comment: i found the sshd_config file, it says:

    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
    HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

Shuold I just copy these 3 files to new server?

Comment: @c2h2 - yes copy those and pub files to the new server. or even better the whole content of /etc/ssh